# Enemies disappear randomly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have implemented various enemies in my game but for now, I'm confronted with a problem when I want to add pre-defined movement to all enemies.

Firstly, the code managing enemies worked fine. The enemies just waited and if the players was too close to him, he attacked.

```
[SerializeField]
private float rotationSpeed = 180;

[SerializeField]
private float movementSpeed = 1f;

[SerializeField]
private float meshRadius = 1f;

private IEnumerator turnTowardsPlayerCoroutine;
private IEnumerator moveTowardsPlayerCoroutine;

private bool isDead = false;

public float speed = 1;

private int maxLife = 3;

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
{
    if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        float playerDistance = Vector3.Distance(collider.transform.position, transform.position);

        if (playerDistance >= 2f * meshRadius)
        {
            turnTowardsPlayerCoroutine = TurnTowardsPlayer(collider.transform);
            moveTowardsPlayerCoroutine = MoveTowardsPlayer(collider.transform);
            StartCoroutine(turnTowardsPlayerCoroutine);
            StartCoroutine(moveTowardsPlayerCoroutine);
        }
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider collider)
{
    if (collider.tag == "Player")
    {
        float playerDistance = Vector3.Distance(collider.transform.position, transform.position);

        if (playerDistance >= 2f * meshRadius)
        {
            StopCoroutine(turnTowardsPlayerCoroutine);
            StopCoroutine(moveTowardsPlayerCoroutine);
        }
    }
}

void OnDeath()
{
    if (isDead)
    {
        return;
    }

    maxLife--;

    if (maxLife <= 0)
    {
        isDead = true;

        GameManager.Instance.NumKilledEnemies++;

        StopCoroutine(turnTowardsPlayerCoroutine);
        StopCoroutine(moveTowardsPlayerCoroutine);

        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}

private IEnumerator TurnTowardsPlayer(Transform player)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(player.position - transform.position, Vector3.up);
        targetRotation.x = 0f;
        targetRotation.z = 0f;

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, targetRotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        yield return 0;
    }
}

private IEnumerator MoveTowardsPlayer(Transform player)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Vector3 playerDirection = transform.position - player.position;
        playerDirection.y = 0;
        playerDirection = playerDirection.normalized;

        Vector3 deltaMovement = playerDirection * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        int layermask = LayerMask.GetMask("Environment");
        Vector3 movingTowards = transform.position - playerDirection * meshRadius + (new Vector3(0f, 0.1f, 0f));
        if (Physics.Raycast(movingTowards, Vector3.down, 0.25f, layermask))
        {
            transform.position -= deltaMovement;
        }

        yield return 0;
    }
}
```

But after that, I wanted to add a predefined movement of enemies if nobody is close to him so I did something like this :

```
private IEnumerator moveDefaultCoroutine;

void Start()
{
    moveDefaultCoroutine = MoveToPosition(new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z + 3), 5);
    StartCoroutine(moveDefaultCoroutine);
}

private IEnumerator MoveToPosition(Vector3 newPosition, float time)
{
    while (true)
    {
        float elapsedTime = 0;
        Vector3 startingPos = transform.position;

        while (elapsedTime < time)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startingPos, newPosition, (elapsedTime / time));
            elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
        elapsedTime = 0;

        while (elapsedTime < 0.8)
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(transform.eulerAngles, new Vector3(0, 180, 0), (elapsedTime / 0.8f));
            elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }

        elapsedTime = 0;

        while (elapsedTime < time)
        {
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(newPosition, startingPos, (elapsedTime / time));
            elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
        elapsedTime = 0;

        while (elapsedTime < 0.8)
        {
            transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Lerp(transform.eulerAngles, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), (elapsedTime / 0.8f));
            elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And here come the problem, when I'm adding this code the enemies disappear randomly... Did I did something wrong ?

Full code here : http://pastebin.com/tzGczv26

Thanks per advance !

PokeRwOw

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ try your question here,hope you will get quick response there

Comment: For any future visitors, question was recreated [here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/109683/enemies-disappear-randomly). Fragmenting our discussions isn't really a great thing, but at least this allows us to keep track of both at the same time so no important details are missed.

Comment: Try logging out some values to determine what exactly is causing your enemy to behave so erratically. Some (possibly) pertinent values may be `newPosition` and `transform.position` in your `MoveToPosition()` method. This would be the first step in narrowing down where exactly the problem lies, which makes it easier for all of us to debug.

Comment: The objects disappearing on screen, but in the Hierarchy they are relocating in the sky and falls to the ground... And this problem seem to be appear if they are 2 types of the same enemy in the same level.